# Setting a double pointer with a calloc

Tags: c, pointers

I am initializing a the Calendar structure blow, but I am having trouble initializing the priority_array.

```
typedef struct task {
   const char *name;
   const char *description;
   struct task *next_task;
} Task;
typedef struct {
   Task **priority_array;
   int max_priority;
} Calendar;
```

I try to initialize it by doing so

```
cal->*priority_array = calloc(max_priority + 1, sizeof(Task));
```

However, I get

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'Task' from type 'void *'
```

If I remove the '*', then I can compile correctly, but priority_task would just be a single pointer.

Why is it that I cannot dereference priority_array to set it to its second pointer

Comment: `cal->*priority_array`???

Comment: Why is it a double pointer? What is the memory layout that you want to address with it?

Comment: You "cannot dereference priority_array to set it to its second pointer" because `priority_array` is uninitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cal->priority_array = calloc(max_priority + 1, sizeof(Task *));
```

That is assuming you allocated cal and set max_priority. The example code is a bit lacking.

Comment: Or, using the object itself rather than the type, `cal->priority_array = calloc(max_priority + 1, sizeof *cal->priority_array);`